# PHP DOM - Getting contents UNDER strong tag

Tags: php, dom

I am attempting to learn DOM for PHP. There does not seem to be alot of tutorials out there for learning the HTML queries. So I ask this question:

I have ran the following code:

```
    <?php
function DOMinnerHTML($element)
{
    $innerHTML = "";
    $children = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child)
    {
        $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument();
        $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true));
        $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML());
    }
    return $innerHTML;
}
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHtmlFile("http://******/business_analyst");
    $x = new DOMXpath($doc);
    foreach ($x->query("//div[@class='content']") as $node)
    {
        echo DOMinnerHTML($node);

    }
    ?>
```

And this returns the following:

```
<div class="content">

        <p>
            <span class="green"> | Elizabethtown Headquarters</span>
        </p>

        <p><strong>Summary</strong><br />
Working with Microsoft SQL Server, evaluate and utilize reporting tools, and work closely with other departments to determine business needs.</p>

<p><strong>Responsibilities</strong></p>

<ul>
<li>Communicate with other functional departments such as Finance, Sales/Marketing, Customer Service, Support Services and other departments to identify business needs.</li>
<li>Gather and formalize business requirements such as for reports, data extracts, third-party vendor application enhancements and internal application development.</li>
<li>Create simple and advanced queries using SQL structured for MS SQL Server.</li>
<li>Evaluate and utilize third-party reporting tools as needed depending on the required solution.</li>
<li>Perform database administration tasks as needed such as creating scheduled batch scripts, monitoring database performance and evaluating backup processes.</li>
<li>Prepare technical and user documentation as needed.</li>
<li>Write scripts and stored procedures as needed.</li>
<li>Work as part of a team to exchange business and technical knowledge in a positive manner.</li>
<li>Perform other duties as required related to analysis, requirements and database related projects.</li>
</ul>

<p><strong>Requirements</strong></p>

<ul>
<li>Minimum 3 years working with Microsoft SQL Server.</li>
<li>Minimum 3 years developing simple and complex SQL queries using MS SQL Server.</li>
<li>Experience writing batch scripts, stored procedures and stored functions.</li>
<li>Experience with business analysis related desktop tools such as Excel and Word.</li>
<li>Experience with third-party reporting tools.</li>
<li>Experience tuning SQL Server databases a plus.</li>
<li>Oracle and MySQL database experience a plus.</li>
<li>Professional attitude and willingness to work independently and as a member of a team.</li>
<li>A.S. Degree and/or B.S. Degree preferred but not required depending on years of experience.</li>
</ul>

        <h2>Apply Now</h2>

        <form class="careers-form" id="business_analyst" method="post" action="http://web1.bluegrasscellular.com/"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div class='hiddenFields'>
<input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="20" />
<input type="hidden" name="URI" value="about/careers/business_analyst" />
<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="open" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="/contact/thanks/%%entry_id%%" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_on_duplicate" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="RET" value="http://web1.bluegrasscellular.com/about/careers/business_analyst" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="careers" />
<input type="hidden" name="ajax_request" value="y" />
<input type="hidden" name="params_id" value="13930914" />
<input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
</div>



            <fieldset>

                <input type="hidden" name="job_title" value="Business Analyst" />
                <input type="hidden" name="job_description" value="Business Analyst" />
                <input type="hidden" name="source" value="website-careers" id="source">
                <input type="hidden" name="message" value="0bba03eb0000000000000000000000071a5c" id="message">


                    <input type="hidden" name="job_location" value="Elizabethtown Headquarters" />


                <label><span class="red">*</span>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" /><br />

                <label><span class="red">*</span>Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" /><br />

                <label><span class="red">*</span>Resume:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file1" />

                <label><span class="red">*</span>Please enter the text as it appears in the box below</label>
                                                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function(){
                    Recaptcha.create('6LduXdcSAAAAAEjc_hSNGCFG-BurosYW8a49xmgv',
                        "recaptcha_container",
                        {
                            theme:'red',
                            lang:'en'
                        }
                    );              
                };
            </script>
            <div id="recaptcha_container"></div>

                <div class="float-clear enews-optin">
<input class="check" style="display: inline; float:left; width: 16px; margin-right: 8px;" type="checkbox" name="enews" value="yes"/>
<label class="check" style="display: inline; padding: 1px; margin: 0; float: left;">Yes, sign me up to receive email updates from Bluegrass Cellular with information on the latest products, services, special offers and discounts.</label>
</div>

                <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" /><br>

                <p class="float-clear"><small><span class="red">*required</span></small></p>

            </fieldset>

        </form>

        <p><a href="/about/careers/">Back to Jobs</a></p>

    </div><!-- /.content-->
```

I am wanting to grab the contents under the strong headings (Summary, Responsibilities, Requirements). Since I cannot seem to find very much help online about this I am asking for your help here! Thanks!

Comment: By _under_ do you mean _within_ ("Requirements") or _after_ ("<ul><li>...")?

Comment: Does EVERY block always have a `<ul>` after the `<strong>` you're interested in? It'd be easy enough to find every strong, then simply use a little relative DOM pathing to get the next ul.

Comment: Yes, the html should never change. I want the contents AFTER the strong. However I do not know how to select a STRONG by the text within. IE... <strong>Requirements</strong> and then get the following text.

Comment: Oh the Summary does not have a <ul>. It is just some text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is just the contents of the `<strong>` nodes, just update your XPath query to the following:

```
//div[@class='content']//strong/text()
```

You can also retrieve the `<strong>` nodes with

```
//div[@class='content']//strong
```

and then retrieve the values from within PHP.

Comment: No, I want the text after the strong tags. Those are just the headings, I am needing the text after the headings.

Comment: exactly what I needed... It for some reason does not grab the <p><strong>Summary</strong><br /> one, but since thats in a <p></p> i can grab that in another query! Thanks!